# when redirected to a page the css files , js , images etc aren't loading

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter. actual page has no problems but when redirected to a page the css files , js , images etc aren't loading

```
<script   src="<?php echo site_url('resource/js/bootstrap.js'); ?>"></script>
<link href="<?php echo  site_url('resource/css/default.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" <?php echo  site_url('resource/css/tab.css'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo  site_url('resource/css/mob.css'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link href="<?php echo  site_url('resource/css/nav.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo  site_url('resource/css/style.css'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo  site_url('resource/font/font.css'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

Comment: check in your console is all css and js are shows 404 if yes then check your base_url()

Comment: why these files are refuse to load when redirected to a page otherwise they work properly

Comment: what is in your console?

Comment: Make a helper file, make an `asset_url()` function, and just point this at `base_url() .'resource/'` - this will then work site wide and keeps code cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to replace **site_url()** with **base_url()**

```
echo base_url(); // http://example.com/website
echo site_url(); // http://example.com/website/index.php
```